# Intellij IDEA: How to view *entire page* of javadoc for a class (e.g. Color.html)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

**TL;DR -**
How do I get the HTML documentation for the entire class all at once, just as I would if using a browser?

**Wordy -**
Whenever I have Intellij IDEA view the "quick documentation" for a class, I get just the documentation for the class *definition itself*.

For instance, when using my particular hotkey-click on Color, I get this popup:
[image]

However what I want is the **entire** html page (the rendered javadoc for the entire file).

This would be akin to what I would find here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

I've never found a built-in for this.

Answer (score 0):

View | [External Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#) is the only way.